# Zend Framework: OpenID 2.0 and Directed Identity

Tags: zend-framework, openid, directed-identity

I have custom OpenID provider and consumer.

The OpenID URL should be hard-coded in the consumer app and will point to my custom provider (let's say: http://login.loc/). Provider app in turn tells the consumer which identity is currently logged in on the server (http://login.loc/johndoe e.g.).

It should be exactly same as implementation of Google or Yahoo OpenID login here at Stack Overflow.

How to implement the login procedure so that the user does not need to provide his OpenID URL?

Answer (score 3):

I found out this technique is called directed identity and is part of OpenID 2.0.

Some general info about it [here](http://barelyenough.org/blog/2007/12/openid-20s-killer-feature/).

The part of specification that describes this is [here](http://openid.net/specs/openid-authentication-2_0.html#discovery).